# PyCharm with GitHub

Tags: github, pycharm

I have my PyCharm IDE set up for Python version 3.7 and it is pushing all config files of the IDE to my GitHub repository even if I don't commit or push the changes automatically.

Is there a way to stop this form happening?

Comment: Add the `.idea/` directory to `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `.gitignore` file and add `.idea` into it.